# Block is transparent in hand, but white on ground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am designing a texture pack for Minecraft. I am experimenting with transparent textures, and so I made stone transparent with black borders. It looks fine in my inventory, and in my hand, but when I place it the transparency turns white and the borders get unevenly thick.

As you can see, the block looks fine in my hand but breaks when I place it.

[image: Blocks not showing tranparency]

Comment: Could you try to see what's the glass block properties in the default texture/resource pack? Not really sure but if it's possible to copy the property of glass to stone and it might fix your problem.

Comment: You need to give the block transparent to attribute

Answer (score 2):

in minecraft, only the blocks that support transparency by default are able to support transparency in a re-textured form, as their render mode is hard-coded into the game.

There are three different types:

1. **no transparency** - a block that doesn't support transparency. This is the majority of all blocks in the game, including stone. If you try to apply a transparent texture to a block like this, the opacity will default back to 100%, which is why the texture is white in your example, and also why the border is thicker in some corners: there probably is a very transparent black shadow in that side, which gets set to full visibility by the game.
2. **partial transparency** - a block that allows for 100% transparent pixels, but all other pixels are set to 100% opacity. Leaves are an example for this block, as they support leaving out pixels, but not making them half-transparent.
3. **full transparency support** - a block that uses the full spectrum of opacity/transparency. Stained glass is a good example of this, as there is a transparent layer of color over all of them.

*There is no way to change which block is rendered which way without mods, so you need to choose the right block for the right job.*

***Items always support full transparency**, which is why it looks correct in your hand, but not when placed down.*

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it isn't transparent, but the weird borders are formed because you put them on all four sides of the texture. If a 1-pixel line were to go next to another 1-pixel line, it would form a 2-pixel line only where they touch. Since your stone textures don't go to infinity, some sides will be thicker than others since the borders combine.

Comment: That was my initial reaction as well, but, as you can see in the screenshot, the white part of a single face is not square, and even the borders on one side are not even (see lower left corner).

Comment: The border is not equally thick on all four sides (looks like some 1px, some 2px), and since the texture for stone is rotated/flipped randomly, you get uneven lines.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the white and leave it blank or find the texture of the clear in the `structure_void`, barrier, glass, or glass pane.